# DNS updated on public internet but not changed in internal VPC AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a domain for example domain.com it is mapping using a Record to IP 123.123.123.123.
Some days ago I change domain mapping to x123.cloudfront.com using CNAME and delete the old one that used A record.
When I check using the internet network it's already mapped to x123.cloudfront.com, but when I check from the internal VPC AWS network it's still mapped to IP 123.123.123.123.

What should I do to update the DNS from the internal network?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you have  private hosted zone associated with the VPC you test from. If you need help doing this , please write here.